# ¿Cómo representar con ggplot esta tabla de datos? R

Tags: r

Quiero representar esta tabla de datos en R :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría hacerlo en una gráfica de este tipo :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De forma que en el eje x aparezca umbral(cajas) y de cada valor salgan dos barras:
Una indicandome en eje y el num de clientes semanales
Otra indicandome en eje y el num de clientes quincenales

Pero no sé de qué forma transformar la tabla para poder hacer esto, pues en el caso de la imagen de ejemplo, añadí una variable que asignara un número a cada día, pero al tener aquí las dos barras que quiero como columnas no sé que paso dar. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Maria, veo que has hecho varias preguntas y no has aceptado ninguna de las repuestas, ¿ninguna ha sido útil? Te sugiero que leas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, por otro lado, con respecto a tu pregunta, deberías agregar el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora  y ademá evitar el uso de las imágenes, en particular con respecto a los datos, agrega un ejemplo en modo texto, y así el que responda, no tenga que transcribir una imagen, en R es tan simple como agregar la salida de `dput(head(datos,20))`. Saludos.

Comment: Hola! Disculpa no sabía como hacer lo de las respuestas. Muchas gracias.